# Nivo Slider not work proper

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

My problem is when I click on slider button/point work properly, but after 4-5 time clicked it was stuck. I have also find solution but not given proper solution.

Also [See link](http://www.oxygenhairsalon.co.uk/)

Thank you

Comment: I got an `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded prototype.js:1131` error in my Chrome Console at your site. Could that have anything to do with your slider?

Comment: Does the answer on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724691/nivoslider-not-working-smoothly-on-magento) maybe solves your problem? (Replacing `$.fn._reverse = [].reverse;` with `$.fn._reverse = []._reverse;` in one of the nivoslider js files.)

Comment: @RoySchoep: ok but how can i resolve this error.

Comment: Open [this file](http://www.oxygenhairsalon.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/hellomix/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js) in you editor and replace `$.fn._reverse = [].reverse;` with `$.fn._reverse = []._reverse;` [This file](http://pastebin.com/0Yzq8EvU) is the file you need (already edited it for you).

Comment: @RoySchoep: can you post your answer as 'Answer' then i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open [this file](http://www.oxygenhairsalon.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/hellomix/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js) in you editor and replace

`$.fn._reverse = [].reverse;`

with

`$.fn._reverse = []._reverse;`

[This is the edited jquery.nivo.slider.js file](http://pastebin.com/0Yzq8EvU).

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724691/nivoslider-not-working-smoothly-on-magento) on StackOverflow